# How to convert Axios code to fetch api for jwt Token

Tags: reactjs, axios, jwt, fetch

I am trying to convert a simple statement of axios to fetch
I have seen this code in tutorial but I am not feasible in axios

```
const { data } = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/login', { email })
```

I have tried it by the below code

```
const { data } = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/login', { email })
```

But it's give me 404 Error

Comment: You need to explicitly declare that you are using a "POST" method in the Headers object.

Comment: Is like that? 
fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(email)
        })

Comment: Not sure about the email (if your API is expecting string or object) or the exact headers, but it could be fine.

Comment: Fetch and Axios have different APIs. If you want to make a request in fetch, _read up on using fetch_.

Answer (score 1):

`Fetch` API is more 'low level' than `axios`. You need to be more verbose. Unless you are sending a `GET` request, you need to explicitely specify the method:

```
fetch('http://localhost:5000/login', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    // some headers of your need, e.g.:
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ email })
})
```

Comment: ok I understand it now

Answer (score 0):

```js
const { data } = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/login', {
method: 'POST',
headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
},
body: JSON.stringify({ email })
})
```